# Cross-domain AJAX requests with IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, jsonp

Cross-domain AJAX requests (made using jQuery 1.7.2) are not performed in IE9 unless the request dataType is set to "jsonp" or "script".

I discovered this issue in framing a request where I did not care about the response and left dataType unspecified (yes, I know I should care about the response).

So, for example, this will work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    type: "GET", // or "POST"
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

But this won't:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    type: "GET" // or "POST"
});
```

By "work" I mean that I see an HTTP request made in Firebug or F12.

Both requests work in other browsers. Setting `jQuery.support.cors = true;` does not affect success, nor does setting crossDomain to true nor cache to false (in the AJAX request).

Why should the success of an AJAX request depend on the dataType requested in just IE? I can understand why it would affect my ability to work with any returned data; I also understand that some servers might reject all requests for a certain dataType (but that is apparently not the case here).

Comment: You need to understand what JSONP is.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I have the same issue, IE9 + jQuery 1.7.2 doing cross domain ajax POSTS to my WebAPI. I have proper CORS support built out on the server side that allows FF/Chrome/Safari to work properly. IE9 simply refuses to issue the pre-flight OPTIONS request to determine CORS support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a question of datatype but of clearly verifying, in the browser, that the server really wants to answer this query.

By imposing [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) you force the server to have a very specific answer (including the method call).

Note that there are now other solutions : you can set, on the server, specific headers (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control)

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing cross domain ajax calls to handle form posts without reloading the page, setting data type to "script" worked for me.

I would be very interested in credible links to info to learn more about why this is. I pulled my hair out for a couple days not understanding why all browsers but IE9 were working.

@dystroy even after putting in headers, that allowed FF to work but didn't make a diffrence in IE9 until I used the script data type

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to write a long script for that. Just simply add this code below and see the magic.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.support.cors = true;
// call your other functions below.....
})
```

Comment: This is an old question that I'm not really interested in pursuing further, but please note that in my initial post I state that I tried setting the `jQuery.support.cors` property to `true`.